# C - Changing pixel color of bmp file

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bmp

I'm pretty new to C and I've been struggling to understand how I should access and modify the RGB values of certain pixels of a bmp file.

The header of my image ends at byte 54, so from there all bytes should hold information about the pixels. One pixel is defined by 3 bytes, holding blue, green, red respectively (since my machine is little endian). I would like to make this pixel black, meaning all 8 bits of those 3 bytes need to be 0.

So my question is this:

How do I access the bits of a byte of a bmp file and set them all to zero?

Thank you.

Comment: Windows has APIs to manipulate BMP files, you don't have to deal with the binaries directly... unless you want to.

Comment: Also bear in mind pixels are only described in 3 bytes if it's a 24-bit RGB Bitmap, there are other formats. Monochromatic for instance, uses only 1 bit per pixel.

Comment: to set a byte to 0, just write a 0 to it. You don't set the 8 bits separately

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

typedef struct{
BYTE rgbtBlue;
BYTE rgbtGreen;
BYTE rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

you can define a struct called `RGBTRIPLE` and reach its individual elements through  `RGBTRIPLE.rgbtBlue` command.(for altering intensity of Blue in your pixel)

You know that your RGBTRIPLEs starts at byte 54, so you can alter your pixels how ever you want. Remember that each RGBTRIPLE represents each pixel starting from bottom right or top left your screen(it is indicated on your BMP. header file) Since we have restricted information about your BMP. file, you can check your own file's properties by matching stated information in your BMP file's header file (first 54 bit) with the informations indicated in this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx

Good Luck.